# MK_CONTROL i WM_MOUSEWHEEL

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to implement zoom feature by using ctrl+ mouse wheel. If i use this code, the active window is scrolling, but not zooming - it looks like all apps that receive this message don't recognize MK_CONTROL flag. Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
while(true)
    {
    WORD wLow=MK_CONTROL;
    WORD wHigh=240;
    WPARAM par= MAKEWPARAM(wLow, wHigh);
    HWND WindowToScroll =  GetForegroundWindow();
    SendMessage(WindowToScroll, WM_MOUSEWHEEL,par,NULL);
    Sleep(1000);
    cout<<WindowToScroll<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `WindowToScroll` implement zooming on _Ctrl+Wheel_?

Comment: Perhaps you'd have a better time with something like `FindWindow` to get the one you want, assuming it actually *does* do something with it.

Comment: But generally GetForegroundWindow finds the window which I want. The problem is that in Spy++ i see that f.ex Firefox receive WM_MOUSEWHEEL message with MK_CONTROL flag set, but only performs scrolling instead of zooming. If I do it manually, in Spy I see message which looks exactly the same like this one send by my program. But in this case it works..

Comment: Maybe Firefox checks without using the `WPARAM` value. Who knows? If you actually want to narrow it down to what you've presented, do it with your own window that 100% for sure does use it.

Comment: Maybe, but system sends the same message when I'm doing it physically and in that case it works. I'm a little bit confused about that and wondering if I can resolve this problem in other way

Comment: What if FF checks whether the control key was down using `GetKeyState`? Your method won't work at all then.

Comment: So is in that case other way to force FF and other apps to do the zoom ?

Comment: Find a documented method to do it rather than trying to fake input? You may also want to check `SendInput`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume that the program uses the MK_CONTROL flag.  That is however not typical, programs very commonly check the actual keyboard state to check for modifiers.  GetKeyState() function.

That's a problem, you cannot fake the keyboard state for another process with SendMessage().  You'll need to use SendInput() instead and actually send a keydown for the control key.  Also good to fake the mouse wheel input.  Don't forget keyup to restore the keyboard state.